# Flask Ajax POST data scope

Tags: ajax, flask

I need to render a Flask template but the ajax data is only accessible within the POST if statement and does not show when I call a get direct after a posted the data.

I have a working ajax here

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/query",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: JSON.stringify({hostname:hostname, bf_id:computerID}),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function () { 
            window.location.href = "/query";
        }
        });
```

});

The data is successfully posted and the redirect is working. But when the redirect calls the function to render the template, the posted ajax cannot be retrieved.

```
@app.route('/query', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query():
hostname=""
if request.method == "POST":
    #these values only exist in if statement
    hostname = request.json['hostname']
    bf_id = request.json['bf_id']

return render_template('query.html', hostname=hostname)
```

Am I using an incorrect work flow?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using an incorrect work flow?

Yes.

1. You make the POST request with the data.
2. You get a response which does things with that data
3. You then make a GET request without the data
4. You get a response which can't do things with the data that it doesn't have

The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request *without loading a whole new page*.

If you want to load a whole new page, then use a regular form submission without involving JavaScript at all.